# (How) Is it possible to convert tables into foreign tables in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, sharding, foreign-data-wrapper

We have a large table in our Postgres production database which we want to start "sharding" using foreign tables and inheritance.

The desired architecture will be to have 1 (empty) table that defines the schema and several foreign tables inheriting from the empty "parent" table. (possible with Postgres 9.5)

I found this well written article https://www.depesz.com/2015/04/02/waiting-for-9-5-allow-foreign-tables-to-participate-in-inheritance/ that explains everything on how to do it from scratch. 
My question is how to reduce the needed migration of data to a minimum.

We have this 100+ GB table now, that should become our first "shard". And in the future we will regulary add new "shards". At some point, the older shards will be moved to another tablespace (on cheaper hardware since they become less important).

**My question now:**
Is there a way to "ALTER" an existing table to be a foreign table instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to use alter table to do this.

You really have to basically do it manually.  This is no different (really) than doing table partitioning.  You create your partitions, you load the data.  You direct reads and writes to the partitions.

Now in your case, in terms of doing sharding there are a number of tools I would look at to make this less painful.  First, if you make sure your tables are split the way you like them first, you can use a logical replication solution like Bucardo to replicate the writes while you are moving everything over.

There are some other approaches (parallelized readers and writers) that may save you some time at the expense of db load, but those are niche tools.

There is no native solution for shard management of standard PostgreSQL (and I don't know enough about Postgres-XL in this regard to know how well it can manage changing shard criteria).  However pretty much anything is possible with a little work and knowledge.

Comment: Thats what I thought. Thanks for the answer!